# How to remove the word "null" in the output FIRSTNAME: NULL?

Tags: c#

```
        string FirstName, LastName = " ";
        char MiddleInitial = ' ';

        Console.Write("Insert  first name: ");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (FirstName.Equals("null"))
        {
            Console.Write("Insert middle initial ");
            Console.Write("\nInsert last name \n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
            MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];
            Console.Write("Insert  last name: ");
            LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        string Month, Year, Day;
        Console.Write("\nInsert birth month: ");
        Month = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Month.Equals("null"))
        {
            Console.Write("Insert birth day ");
            Console.Write("\nInsert birth year \n");

            Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
            Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}", FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
            Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH MONTH:");
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH DAY:");
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH Year:");
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTHDAY:");
          
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Insert birth day: ");
            Day = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Insert birth year: ");
            Year = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
            Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}", FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
            Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH MONTH: {0}", Month);
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH DAY: {0}", Day);
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTH YEAR: {0}", Year);
            Console.WriteLine("BIRTHDAY:{0}/{1}/{2}", Month, Day, Year);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The program runs correctly the only matter is how can I make the program output to be like this:

```
Insert  first name: null
Insert middle initial
Insert last name

Insert birth month: null
Insert birth day
Insert birth year

Your record
FIRST NAME:
MIDDLE INITIAL:
LASTNAME:
BIRTH MONTH:
BIRTH DAY:
BIRTH Year:
BIRTHDAY:
```

But what the program currently outputs is this:

```
Insert  first name: null
Insert middle initial
Insert last name

Insert birth month: null
Insert birth day
Insert birth year

Your record
FIRST NAME:null
MIDDLE INITIAL:
LASTNAME:
BIRTH MONTH:
BIRTH DAY:
BIRTH Year:
BIRTHDAY:
```

As you can see it display

```
FIRST NAME:null    // It should be empty
```

The program should display nothing if I insert two "null" words without sacrificing others function.

But if I insert one null and then I insert the value of the others should display like this

```
Insert  first name:James
Insert middle initial:F
Insert last name:Capili

Insert birth month:null
Insert birth day
Insert birth year

Your record
FIRST NAME:James
MIDDLE INITIAL:F
LASTNAME:Capili
BIRTH MONTH:
BIRTH DAY:
BIRTH Year:
BIRTHDAY:
```

---

```
Insert  first name: null
Insert middle initial
Insert last name

Insert birth month: 04
Insert birth day:14
Insert birth year:2000

Your record
FIRST NAME:
MIDDLE INITIAL:
LASTNAME:
BIRTH MONTH:04
BIRTH DAY:14
BIRTH Year:2000
BIRTHDAY:04/14/2000
```

What is the best logic to do here?

Comment: Actually having the user enter the text "null" seems like a strange way of going about things to me. I'd suggest you just let the user leave it blank instead. Then it will already be an empty string.

Comment: but it should be work that way it is a challenging and also a relieving one if i manage to do it correctly.

Comment: So the program cannot handle a user named "Null"? Bad (and completly unnecessary). https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Handle the null value through FirstName == "null" ? "" : FirstName

  ```
    using System;

    class Program
    {
    public static void data()
    {
        string FirstName, LastName = " ";
        char MiddleInitial = ' ';

    Console.Write("Insert  first name: ");
    FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (FirstName.Equals("null"))
    {
        Console.Write("Insert middle initial ");
        Console.Write("\nInsert last name \n");

    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
        MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        Console.Write("Insert  last name: ");
        LastName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    string Month, Year, Day;
    Console.Write("\nInsert birth month: ");
    Month = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Month.Equals("null"))
    {
        Console.Write("Insert birth day ");
        Console.Write("\nInsert birth year \n");

        Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
        Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}", FirstName == "null" ? "" : FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
        Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH MONTH:");
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH DAY:");
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH Year:");
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTHDAY:");


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Insert birth day: ");
        Day = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Insert birth year: ");
        Year = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
        Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}",  FirstName == "null" ? "" : FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
        Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH MONTH: {0}", Month);
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH DAY: {0}", Day);
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTH YEAR: {0}", Year);
        Console.WriteLine("BIRTHDAY:{0}/{1}/{2}", Month, Day, Year);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

   }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data();
    }
   }
  ```